# Domain Transfer

Tags: hosting, domain, nameserver

I'm going a bit crazy.  I have a domain name, buzzonstage.com, registered with GoDaddy(not my choice lol)  and the hosting is with linode.  I set the nameservers at GoDaddy to ns1.linode.com, ns2.linode.com etc, and when I do a traceroute, check ns records or a records, they all point to the correct ip.  However, when I actually enter the url on the site it goes to the old place where I pointed.  I even flushed my cache on my mac with dscacheutil.

Please help! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure it isn't your browser cache?  If you're using firefox quit out of it all the way.

Also here it is from where I'm at:

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   buzzonstage.com
Address: 173.230.133.91

Comment: Agreed - I've also seen some ISPs cache DNS for much longer than they should. If you query the authoritative servers for the domain directly and they answer correctly, then you just have to wait for your resolver's cache entries to expire.

Comment: How can I query the servers?  Not sure how to do that.  And I even tried on my iphone and it still goes to the old site!  Lol going crazy :)

Comment: that is the right address though - the non-auth answer.

Comment: Is your iphone on your wireless?  Same network as your mac and therefore using the same DNS provided by your provider?  Try this:  force it.  Add the IP and hostname to your /etc/hosts file.  Then restart your browser and try it - should go to your site.  I get an nginx server error when I try your domain.

Comment: hey guys thanks a lot everyone!  It transfered over the next day.  I do wonder what was causing it though since ALL the stats i was getting were pointing to the correct server.  I didn't try the /etc/hosts file hack though.  And my phone was on my wifi so that could've been causing it as well.

Comment: Right, your local network or your ISP had the DNS cached to the old location.